# How to import uikit js in react js without using the uikit component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uikit

I'm having a hard time importing my uikit.js in my react js component.

This is my import sample, the uikit.css works but the uikit.js provides this kind of error:

```
 import './uikit/css/uikit.css';
 import './uikit/js/uikit.js';

  Line 5:     'define' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 5:     'define' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 573:   'DocumentTouch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 1107:  'MSGesture' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 5039:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 5043:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 6679:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
```

Comment: import UIkit from 'uikit'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem. First of all install uikit with

`npm i uikit --save`

Then import it into your application as you would any other package.
If you used `create-react-app`, and you are calling it in `src` directory, just do

`import '../node_modules/uikit/css/uikit.css'`

else determine the depth and adjust the relative path accordingly

Comment: You forgot the dist part

Comment: The OP has an interesting question, in my opinion. Why doesn't it work if you download the library as a zip file, plonk them down in your project, and import them using what appear to be valid relative paths? 

Comment: Where is `uikit.js` that we need? Will the CSS work without UIkit JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

I did it by doing the following;

1. install uikit * npm i uikit --save or yarn add uikit --save
2. Go to the index.js file and include this so u can use it in any component;

   ```
    import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
   ```

   or/and

   ```
   import "uikit/dist/css/uikit-core.min.css";
   ```

NB: Don't forget to include the uikit javascript by including this in your index.js file too.

```
 import "uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js";
```

Hopefully, this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget, use `data-uk-...` instead of `uk-...` in react. For example:

```
<ul className="uk-grid" data-uk-grid>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

- according to:
  https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#component-usage